# Работа с Geokoding Google Maps

Tags: php, google-maps-api, google-maps

Как можно при помощи Гугл-карты отметить все города-побратимы (имеющие одинаковое название)?
Я делал вот так:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Лаба</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?
sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
var settings = {
zoom: 15,
center: latlng,
mapTypeControl: true,
mapTypeControlOptions: {style:
google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
navigationControl: true,
navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
settings);
var companyPos = news.maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Санкт
Петербург&output=xml&key=123456;
var companyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: companyPos,
map: map,
});
}
</script>
</head>
```

В итоге должно быть две метки, так как есть 2 Санкт-Петербурга — один в России, другой в Штатах, — но у меня только одна. Пробовал менять город на другой, к примеру, Слободка — село такое, их в Украине валом, — они мне выдаются по очереди, а не все вместе.

Comment: ии?) неужели никто не знает\  не хочет подсказать студенту?